# htaccess change location of api and redirect all requests

Tags: .htaccess

i had my api located on

```
/public_html/old/app/index.php
```

in this /old/app there is an .htaccess file the following

```
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</ifModule>
```

no i want to move my app to another location

```
/public_html/v1/app/index.html
```

what should i add to the above htaccess to redirect all calls from /old/app folder to /v1/app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give full path of new `index.html` in target:

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
Options -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ /v1/app/index.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /v1/app/index.html [L]
```

Comment: Thanks this works fine in browser, but raise an error from app :(

Comment: Browser works same way as any other web client. It just sends a web request to server. What error are you getting?

Comment: error with empty state, and no response :(, same like you get if cors are not right.

Comment: Then it might not be rewrite related. Rules can only rewrite to correct handler and rest should be in the code or framework you're using.

Comment: indeed it wasn't rewrite related !, i contacted hosting support they replied it was a chmod problem, something like folders must be 0755. they fix it and it now works. thanks @anubhava